# Como hacer para que el usuario ingrese el nombre del archivo que sera utilizado? Java

Tags: java, zip

Buenas tardes este programa comprime carpetas en zip, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que el programa me pida el nombre de la carpeta que se va a comprimir y comprima solo la que el usuario ingrese su nombre y el archivo zip que regrese tenga el mismo nombre de la carpeta antes de comprimirla, todas las carpetas estarán en un directorio raiz, agradezco mucho su ayuda, anexo el codigo:

```
String pathZipInput = "C:/ZIP/pro";
String pathOutputZip = "/ZIP/pro/pro.zip";{
try {
      String path="C:/ZIP/pro";                                
      File folder = new File(path);                           
     String folderName=folder.getAbsoluteFile().getName();     
      System.out.println(folderName);                         

FileSystemView fsv = new DirectoryRestrictedFileSystemView(new File("C:/ZIP/pro"));

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(pathOutputZip);               
   ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
       parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
       parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

 zipFile.addFolder(pathZipInput, parameters);
} 
catch (ZipException e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
}
```

Comment: consola? web? escritorio? depende donde estes es la forma en que usuario va a ingresar el nombre, o buscar la carpeta...

Comment: Por el momento en consola, lo quiero hacer web, pero me interesa primero que me funcione en consola, uso eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un scanner.

```
String pathZipInput = "C:/ZIP/pro";
String pathOutputZip = "/ZIP/pro/pro.zip";{
try {
    String path="C:/ZIP/pro";                                
    File folder = new File(path);                           
    String folderName=folder.getAbsoluteFile().getName();     
    System.out.println(folderName);
    Scanner scaner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Inserte nombre del fichero: ");
    String filename = scaner.next();
    FileSystemView fsv = new DirectoryRestrictedFileSystemView(new File("C:/ZIP/pro"));

   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path+"/"+filename);               
   ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
   parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
   parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

   zipFile.addFolder(pathZipInput, parameters);
} 
catch (ZipException e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Para que ésto sea válido como resúesta debería ser mucho mas amplia. Mientras tanto es recomendable que lo dejes como un comentario